# How to remove duplicates of column by giving appropriate value to its label in the row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel table as follows (contains more data than displayed):

[image]

First column contains `ids`, second column contains `labels` and the row contains `unique labels` without any repetition.
Here, I need to remove the duplicates in the `ids`, by giving value `1` to the appropriate `label` column per row.

The expected out is:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Are you aware of `.groupby()`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: What is your go-to way of doing this. You have tagged different languages.

Comment: pandas package in python or excel vba formula @JvdV

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `pivot` in python pandas package